# MVC5 Rewriting Routing Attribute - Default page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am attempting to switch from RouteConfig to Routing Attributes.

I am following along the Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 book from Adam Freeman and I'm trying to convert the following code that handles the paging of clients.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
      name: null,
      url: "{controller}/Page{page}",
      defaults: new { action = "Index", status = (string)null },
      constraints: new { page = @"\d+" }
  );
```

This works great! As I go to different URLs, the links look very nice

```
 http://localhost:65534/Client - Default page
 http://localhost:65534/Client/Page2 - Second page
```

Now I've decided to try out Url Attributes and having a bit of problems when it comes to how 'pretty' the links are.  All of the links are working fine, but it's the 'routing rewriting' that I am trying to fix.

Here are the important parts of my controller.

```
[RoutePrefix("Client")]
[Route("{action=index}/{id:int?}")]

public class ClientController : Controller {

    [Route("Page{page:int?}")]

    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string search = null, int page = 1) {
```

With the attribute above the Index, going to /Client or to /Client/Page gives me a 404.

Adding a blank route to catch the default page

```
    [Route("Page{page:int?}")]
    [Route]
```

Works for /Client and /Client/Page3, but now the rewriting of the URL is messed up.  Clicking on page 3 of the pager gives me a URL of

```
    http://localhost:65534/Client?page=3
```

which is not what I want.  Changing the routing to

```
    [Route("Page{page:int?}")]
    [Route("{page=1:int?}")]
```

Works almost 100%, but the default link for /Client is now

```
    http://localhost:65534/Client/Page
```

So, I am now asking for help.  How can I correctly convert the original MapRoute to the attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
[Route("", Order = 1)]
[Route("Page{page:int}", Order = 2)]
```

**UPDATE**

Plainly and simply, the routing framework is dumb. It doesn't make decisions about which route is the most *appropriate*, it merely finds a matching route and returns. If you do something like:

```
Url.Action("Index", "Client", new { page = 1 })
```

You're expecting the generated URL to be `/Client/Page1`, but since you have a route where `page` is essentially optional, it always will choose that route and append anything it can't stuff into the URL as a querystring, i.e. `/Client?page=1`. The only way to get around this is to actually name the route you want and use that named route to generate the URL. For example:

```
[Route("", Order = 1)]
[Route("Page{page:int}", Name = "ClientWithPage", Order = 2)]
```

And then:

```
Url.RouteUrl("ClientWithPage", new { page = 1 })
```

Then, you'll get the route you expect because you're directly referencing it.

**UPDATE #2**

I'm not sure what you mean by "go into PagedList.MVC and add a name property to it". It doesn't require any core changes to the code because PagedList already has support for custom page links. Just change your pager code to something like:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfItems, page => Url.RouteUrl("ClientWithPage", new { page = page }))
```

And you'll get the URL style you want. Attribute routing can be a bit more finicky than traditional routing, but I'd hardly call it useless. It's far more flexible than traditional routing, but that flexibility has some costs.

Comment: I had previously tried the 'Order' attribute without luck.  I still get **Client?page=3** and changing the order has no effect on the problem.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the extra explanation.  This completely invalidates any possible use for URL Redirection with attributes then and makes it a worthless feature.  There's no chance I'm going to go into PagedList.MVC and add a name property to it.  I'll just go back to the RoutingConfig file.

Comment: Thanks for taking the extra time to get me straight on how to do this properly!  I ended up with [Route] and [Route("Page{page:int}", Name = "ClientPaging")] since the Order had no effect.